# Deploying Istio Envoy filter gives 503 service unavailable

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, envoyproxy

In kubernetes cluster, with istio running, I have deployed sample authorization service with jwt policy. Making a curl request works as expected.
Now, I need to make an external authorization callout with dummy api to test out my authorization service. I created virtualservice, destinationrule etc. I also deployed istio envoy filter with details:

```
  filters:
    - filterConfig:
        httpService:
          authorizationRequest:
            allowedHeaders:
              patterns:
                - exact: authorization
          serverUri:
            cluster: outbound|8080||authservice.default.svc.cluster.local
            timeout: 5.000s
            uri: http://authservice.default.svc.cluster.local:8080
      filterName: envoy.ext_authz
      filterType: HTTP
```

But after running envoy filter I get 503 service unavailable. I tried chaning the namespace in envoyffilter but still the same error.
Please let me know anyway to achieve service callout with filter `envoy.ext_authz`.

Comment: A 503 can happen when the service is known to the cluster (because a kubernetes service exists) but the destination service does not run istio proxy. As well if your service is a kubernetes service then you must have a cluster named after the service.

Comment: istio proxy is also working and cluster is also defined. I modified the envoyfilter configured in GKE with Istio installed.  Now it gives 404 error for any external http api call.  Problem is `filterName: envoy.ext_authz` not redirecting to serverUri configs setup above. Any suggestion how to handle this?

Comment: Just a little more information regarding this issue, it should be noted that [Istio on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview) is still in beta and therefore not all functions may be available. However, there is a command used to diagnose some issues (like configuration) called [istioctl](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl-analyze/#analyzing-live-clusters-local-files-or-both).

Comment: It may, as well, be of some help to look at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy) for more information on using [Envoy Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy). More information in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/exposing-grpc-services-on-gke-using-envoy-proxy#alternative_application_layer_load_balancers) describes the use of Istio and Envoy Proxy.

Comment: @esha ingle, can you please provide more details on used versions of GKE and Istio-addon.

Comment: GKE is 14 and istio is 1.1.17

Comment: Also is having an HTTP service as an external authorization service supported in istio?

Comment: Ok, to sum up you are tying to enforce the end-user authentication for the dummy API service using JWT authentication, with token being issued by in-cluster auth. service (part of service mesh with mTLS), is it right ?
BTW. How do you test the end-user authentication with curl, inside or outside the K8S cluster ?

Comment: 503 error code in your case suggests that your client is trying to talk plain text to mTLS enabled Service.